# grails google plus plugin

Tags: grails, google-plus, grails-plugin

Is there any example out there for google plus oAuth2 for grails?
I see a [plugin on github](https://github.com/IntelliGrape/Grails-Google-Plus-Plugin) with [documentation](https://github.com/IntelliGrape/Grails-Google-Plus-Plugin/wiki/Google-Plus-for-Grails)

This one seems to be 2 years old and I could not find any examples of using this plugin.
I am willing to try this. but want to know if there are any other plugins out there which are up-to-date?

Answer (score 0):

I have had success using this one: http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-oauth-google, but it requires the use of the Spring Security Oauth Plugin: http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-oauth